# Clone read bytes of BinaryReader

Tags: c#, .net, binaryreader

I'm using a BinaryReader to parse certain data. I would like to copy the read bytes to a secondary stream. How can I do that?

If I derive from BinaryReader (I need to do that for a different reason anyway, actually), which methods do I need to overwrite for correct behavior?

Comment: Dear downvoter: Mind explaining what the problem is? Is this a duplicate (even tho I could not find this in search)?

Comment: Do not derive, encapsulate. Create a new stream class, and create the `BinaryReader` over this stream, while your own class will wrap the inner stream in itself. So when `BinaryReader` calls `Read`, it will be on your stream, which will do the reading from the underlying stream, and writing the data it read to another stream during the same `Read` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryReader` isn't a real `Stream`... It is more an overlay on another stream. You could:

```
using (var yourStream = /* ... */)
using (var br = new BinaryReader(yourStream))
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Important the true, so that the ms remains open!
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            var readed = br.ReadInt32();
            bw.Write(readed); 
            // All the basic types are supported by various overlaods
        }

        // Here you have your ms... If you want to reread it:
        ms.Position = 0;

        using (var br2 = new BinaryReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            // Reread it
        }

        // Or copy it to another stream, or do whatever you want
    }
}
```

If you simply want to duplicate a stream on another stream while you are reading it, you can use something like:

```
public class CopyStream : Stream
{
    // This is the stream you want to read your data from
    public Stream ReadStream { get; set; }

    // This is the "logger" stream, where a copy of read data will be put
    public Stream LogStream { get; set; }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int res = ReadStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        if (LogStream != null)
        {
            if (res > 0)
            {
                LogStream.Write(buffer, offset, res);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        int res = ReadStream.ReadByte();

        if (LogStream != null)
        {
            if (res >= 0)
            {
                LogStream.WriteByte((byte)res);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

You'll need to implement/`throw NotImplementedException()` many other methods, because `Stream` is an `abstract class`. Right click on the `Stream`, `Implement Abstract Class` will speedup this.

The basic use is:

```
var cs = new CopyStream
    {
        ReadStream = yourStream,
        LogStream = whereyouwanttoWriteStream,
    };

using (var br = new BinaryReader(CopyStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
{
    // Here you can read normally from the BinaryReader.
    // Everything you read will be copied to LogStream 
}
```

Note that subclassing `BinaryReader` is quite complex, because each method loads the data in a different way, so there isn't a single "point of interception".

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work for me, because the source is not seekable (it is a network stream).

Comment: In the example the MemoryStream is where you copy the data. Where there is the bw.Write you first should have a br.Read from your stream

Comment: Indeed. But I am using _many_ Reads, so I want to automate the process of cloning the data.

Comment: Right. That is what I was looking for. But the question is: Which methods do I need to override? I'm fairly certain I only need to override a few of them, as they are re-used internally. But which ones?

Comment: @mafu The two `Read` I wrote, and the `Dispose(bool disposing)` if you want your other streams to be automatically disposed. The `Stream.Close` calls the `Dispose(bool disposing)`, so the `Stream.Close` is already ok. For everything else... There shouldn't be anything to write... And then, if there is, you'll get a `NotImplementedException` and you'll find it :-)

Comment: Ok, it would be great if it's only those two methods. But I'm not sure why there should be a NIE - I'm only subclassing a BinaryReader, so all other methods are untouched (but they should _hopefully_ use the updates ReadByte/ReadBytes methods).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73590/discussion-between-xanatos-and-mafu).

Comment: Correction: I found that ReadByte should not be overwritten, as it internally calls Read. (Luaan got that right)

Comment: @mafu The error was mine, in general the ReadByte() should call `ReadStream.ReadByte` and not `base.ReadByte`. I'm not sure all streams call from ReadByte the Read(byte[]). Corrected in last edit

Answer (score 1):

Streams are meant to be encapsulated, not overriden:

```
public class DuploStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _underlyingStream;
    private readonly Stream _copyStream;

    public DuploStream(Stream underlyingStream, Stream copyStream)
    {
        _underlyingStream = underlyingStream;
        _copyStream = copyStream;
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _underlyingStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length { get { throw new NotSupportedException(); } }
    public override long Position { get { throw new NotSupportedException(); } set { throw new NotSupportedException(); } }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bytesRead = _underlyingStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        _copyStream.Write(buffer, offset, bytesRead);

        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

Then, instead of creating `BinaryReader` on top of your underlying stream, you build it on top of `DuploStream`, passing the underlying stream and the copy stream.